# Provide Some Details To End User When ELMAH Catches ASP.NET Error

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, elmah

So as the title states, I would like to give some kind of detail to the end user as Elmah is being used on a corporate Internet where I work, however, I don't want them to see too much detail.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elmah is nothing but one HTTPModule. You can go about your normal exception handling routines in your code or global.asax file and show whatever you want to the user